# Как задать фиксированное положение элемента в блоке со скроллом?

Tags: html, jquery, css, прокрутка

Объясню на примере выпадающего списка со смайлами в контакте.  Мне нужно, чтобы подложка со табами для переключения смайлов сохраняло свою позицию при скроллинге родительского контейнера со смайлами. Как это можно сделать? Наподобие `position:fixed`, но внутри блока, а не браузера. Надеюсь, не запутал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так, а в чём проблема.

[image: Скрин]

Или я не правильно понял вопрос?

Comment: просто запутался в position:fixed, а он тут и не нужен) Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Используйте параметр `position` со свойством `fixed` в CSS.
Позиционирование задаётся относительно родителя, который может быть и блок.
Примеры:

- [Как зафиксировать слой, чтобы он оставался на одном месте при прокрутке страницы?](http://htmlbook.ru/faq/kak-zafiksirovat-sloi-chtoby-ostavalsya-na-odnom-meste)
- [Позиционирование блока относительно родителя с помощью position:fixed](http://dimox.name/position_fixed_for_child_block/)

Comment: Старайтесь давать ссылкам осмысленные названия. "Здесь" и "скачать" использовать не следует.

Comment: Неа, не выходит. задаю родителю position:relative а элементу position:fixed - все равно позиционируется относительно окна. проблема еще усугубляется тем, что таких блоков с элементами должно быть на странице несколько